# Creating a specific color palette in R for Leaflet maps

Tags: leaflet

In R, I want my leaflet color pallet to gradually change from dark purple at 0 to very light purple at 0.999, and then white at 1. And from 1 to the max in dataset, it goes from very light orange at 1.001 to dark orange at the max. Here is what I tried so far, but I could not get white at 1. Instead, the code below made white the halfway value between 0 and the max. Thanks!

```
pal2 <- colorNumeric(
  palette = c("#5A009D", "#FFFFFF", "#FF8C00"),
  domain = c(0, 1, max(Data$A)))
map <- leaflet() %>%
  
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png") %>%
  
  addLegend(position = "bottomright",
            pal = pal2,
            values = Data$A,
            title = "A",
            opacity = 0.75) %>% 
  
  addPolygons(data = Data,
              fillColor = ~pal2(Data$A),
              fillOpacity = 0.75, 
              weight = .01)
```